# Duplicate id in list

Tags: webservices, soap

My service is working fine for single record insert when i send bulk records at that time it showing soapenv:ClientSystem.ListException: Duplicate id in list: 01ti0000002gUP1AAM Class.Sample.behaviourOfWebService: line 235, column 1

the error line is Database.upsert(pList)

```
   p.productCode = pCode;
   p.name =pName;
   pList.add(p); 
}
```

Comment: The error is because you are adding the same instance to a List more than once. Its hard to tell where in your 197 lines of code the error is happening because the error is being reported on line 235 but the code you supplied is only 197 lines long. Can you add details on the line that is throwing the error?

Comment: @BarCotter Database.upsert(pList);  error occuring point

Comment: @BarCotter I provided my whole code.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the offending code (I formatted it to make it more readable). The issue is that if there are multiple records with the same `pCode` then you will end up getting the same `Product2` record from the `existpccMap`, which would then be added to the `pList` more than once, causing this error.

```
for(Product2 p2 : [select id,productCode from Product2 where ProductCode IN : pCodeSet]) {
    existpccMap.put(p2.productCode,p2);
}
for(integer j=0; j< req.accounts[k].prods.size(); j++) {

   if (existpccMap.containsKey(req.accounts[k].prods[j].pCode)) {
     p = existpccMap.get(req.accounts[k].prods[j].pCode);
   } else {
     p = new Product2();
   }
   p.productCode = req.accounts[k].prods[j].pCode;
   p.name =req.accounts[k].prods[j].pName;
   pList.add(p); 
}
```

On solution would be to use a Set to store your records (instead of pList) that need to be updated and then convert to a List before doing the update, but this solution may be hiding an underlying issue with your nested loops.

Comment: May i know what i have to do.

Comment: "On solution would be to use a Set to store your records that need to be updated and then convert to a List before doing the update."

Comment: i am using like this  Map<string,Product2> existpccMap = new Map<string,Product2>();
   set<string> pCodeSet = new set<string>();

Comment: If you use `Set<Product2> pSet` to store the Product2s that you want to update and then convert the Set to a List right before updating you will avoid the issue of duplicate records in the List.

Comment: Can you provide update code.for me.

Comment: I tried as per u r request convert the set to list but it showing an error list out of bounds

Comment: Its impossible to know why that error is happening with the limited information you have given. Here is what you should be doing before the update: `List<Product2> pList = new List<Product2>(); pList.addAll(pset); update pList;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13286/discussion-between-sathya-and-barcotter)

Comment: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements Class.Ctest5.behaviourOfWebService:

Comment: Your question has been answered in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28980/before-insert-or-upsert-list-must-not-have-two-identically-equal-elements